# Saving CFDictionaryRef in Core Data

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, core-foundation

Im trying to save CFDictionaryRef to my core data model and I cant really find information on how to do so.

It will be immensely appreciated if someone could supply more information about it

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot save dictionaries to `CoreData`.
You could however try to convert it to a NSData first and convert it back to a dictionary when before using it. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157356/converting-nsdictionary-object-to-nsdata-object-and-vice-versa) post.

Comment: or use a [transformable attribute](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html)...

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way to save an NSDictionary into CoreData is with NSValueTransformers.

I don't know if it works with CFDictionaries however.  There is no mention of it working or not.  With toll free bridging however it sure *seems* like it should work.

If it were me, I'd try using the value transformer.  If that doesn't work, you can easily convert the CFDictionaryRef into an NSDictionary with:

```
NSDictionary *dictionaryObject = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionaryRef];
```