# Converting a NSDictionary contents into NSData

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary, nskeyedarchiver

I have an `NSDictionary` (which I get from querying in sqlite) which contains bytes. Here is a sample:

`Rects = "<62706c69 73743030 d4010203 04050824 25542474 6f705824 6f626a65 63747358 24766572 73696f6e 59246172 63686976...`

I want to convert this using the `NSKeyedUnarchiver`, but what is the right way to do it?

This is what I did:

```
NSData *data = [rectDict objectForKey:@"Rects"];
NSArray *rectArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectWithData:data];
```

But this returns *NULL*. How will I do this?

**NOTE:** I used `NSArray` as the unarchiver because the data to be unarchived is an array containing custom objects.

**UPDATE:**
To clarify, the dictionary contains the archived object. The whole dictionary is **not** archived, just the content. That's what I'm trying to get.

Comment: possible duplicate of [converting NSDictionary object to NSData object and vice-versa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157356/converting-nsdictionary-object-to-nsdata-object-and-vice-versa)

Comment: @ParagBafna can you please explain how come my question is a possible duplicate of that question? I would gladly accept it if it is really a possible duplicate, but I just can't find the solution for that question to be appropriate in my situation. So kindly explain.