# NSUserDefaults or NSCache - best way to store data

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, caching

I'm building an IOS application, which will basically helps the users to see the orders he made on my website.

On the application startup, the list of his order reloads automatically. What I'm trying to do here is to "save" this data into something to be able to show him his orders even if he's not connected to the internet.

I already used the `NSUserDefaults` class to save the credentials but I'm not sure this is the right way of saving more consistent data (which here consist of an `NSArray` of `Order`).

I heard about the `NSCache` class which could also be a possibility, but I don't really which one would be the best in my case.

Could someone give me some tips about it please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best would be create a NSManagedObject custom class for your order class, and store the orders in core data. For details see [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started) which is enough for solving this problem (and easy to understand the necessary basics of Core Data).

Good luck!

Comment: +1 This could be a good idea to use if there is a lot of data to store.

Answer (score 6):

You are indeed doing the right thing by using `NSUserDefaults`. You may convert your object to `NSData` if needed using `NSKeyedArchiver/NSKeyedUnArchiver`. Refer here: 
[converting NSDictionary object to NSData object and vice-versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157356/converting-nsdictionary-object-to-nsdata-object-and-vice-versa)

Answer (score 0):

CoreData is the best way for your app to store data. Try using coredata.