# Is there an open source category on NSDictionary to quickly convert it from/to NSData?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsdictionary, nsdata

I couldn't find it so I am about to write one, but before I reinvent the wheel... is there a category which adds this functionality?

Of course everything in the NSDictionary is expected to conform to NSCoding but that is fine.

Comment: Would [`NSJSONSerialization`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) be sufficient? If not, then what serialization format do you want?

Comment: Yes NSJSONSerialization or NSKeyedArchiver would be sufficient. Just need something with good performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If everything conforms to NSCoding, it sounds like a prime candidate for `NSKeyedArchiver` / `NSKeyedUnarchiver`.  If you are only supporting iOS 5+, you could also consider `NSJSONSerialization` if you need it to be human readable.  In that case, you are limited to JSON-supported objects though (Array, dictionary, string, number, null).

Comment: Why would it be wasting your time?  You can do the whole operation in one line.

Comment: I've also seen people use `NSPropertyListSerialization` to serialize `NSDictionary` entries, too, but I like your suggestion even more.

Comment: This answer shows how it goes. A couple of lines, not just one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157356/converting-nsdictionary-object-to-nsdata-object-and-vice-versa

Comment: @openfrog That answer is needlessly long.  You can do everything with just one line -> `[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myObject];`